# Running jwacs (lisp program) under 64 bit windows

Tags: javascript, lisp, common-lisp, preprocessor

For years I have been using the javascript-preprocessor jwacs. I use it as a commandline utility (jwacs.exe). Jwacs is written in lisp. I don't know what version of lisp. The problem I have is that jwacs.exe does not work under 64 bits windows versions. It shows the following error:

validation of reserved space too short.
VirtualAlloc: 0x1e7.
ensure_space: failed to validate 1044480 bytes at 0x02100000
(hint: Try "ulimit -a"; maybe you should increase memory limits.)

I tried to run it in windows-xp-compatible mode, and also as administrator but nothing works. I also tried to contact the maker of jwacs, James Wright (james@chumsley.org) but he doesn't answer his mail.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: From looking at a list of features it looks like jwacs is basically obsolete; JS does all those things natively now. So the solution I propose is to learn about modules and async await. That'll probably take less time than installing a virtual machine or whatever that still runs the exe.

Comment: Interesting, but not practical. With this solution I would have to modify and test more than 30000 lines of code.

Comment: In that case we're back at running a 32bit version of Windows in a virtual machine, I guess?

Comment: If you want I can try to build a 64 bit Windows executable for you. Let me know.

Comment: Well, mac, I would appreciate it if you made a 64 bit windows executable for me,

Comment: I have uploaded the executable here: https://gofile.io/d/DSmYT3

Comment: Thank you very much, mac. I have tested it and it produces the same output as the 32 bits version.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.

Comment: @Danny Please consider accepting my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer this for Windows, but jwacs turns out to be easy to rebuild and use. The sources are available [on github](https://github.com/chumsley/jwacs) and built cleanly for me.

Indeed, jwacs is available in [Quicklisp](https://github.com/chumsley/jwacs.git), so on a system with Quicklisp installed, the task of loading it is as simple as `(ql:quickload "jwacs")`.

It's also surprisingly easy to rebuild the binary (it surprised me, anyway).  If you check out the repo, then put a file with these contents in the top directory:

```lisp
(in-package :cl-user)

#-ASDF
(error "Doomed")

(load "jwacs.asd")
(asdf:make "jwacs")
```

Then, if you are using [SBCL](http://www.sbcl.org/) for instance

```
$ sbcl --load build-jwacs.lisp
```

will result in some small noise from the compiler, and then write a binary which looks like it's what you need:

```
$ ./jwacs
===============================================================================
jwacs - Javascript With Advanced Continuation Support
version: 0.3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jwacs: No target specified
Usage: jwacs [options] <main_source_file>
[...]
```

I also built it using LispWorks on a mac, and it was similarly painless.

So, *once you have a working CL environment running*, the problem becomes easy to solve.  Unfortunately that leaves you with the problem of getting a working Lisp environment on Windows.  And I can't help with that because I'm not a Windows person and I hesitate to make recommendations.  However searching for `Common Lisp Windows` is probably useful: this must be something that plenty of people do.  It does look as if [Portacle](https://portacle.github.io/) might be a good place to start, although I have not used it.

I'm sorry this isn't a complete answer, but I hope it will help you find a solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried building this on Windows. After some tinkering I am stuck this compilation error:  wrote C:/Users/marti/AppData/Local/cache/common-lisp/sbcl-2.0.0-win-x64/C/lisp/jwacs/external/yacc-tmpGHU3ALSV.fasl
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.442
While evaluating the form starting at line 7, column 0
  of #P"C:/lisp/jwacs/build-jwacs.lisp":

debugger invoked on a UIOP/LISP-BUILD:COMPILE-FILE-ERROR in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10010B0523}>:
  COMPILE-FILE-ERROR while compiling #<CL-SOURCE-FILE "jwacs" "external" "yacc"> Can you help?

Comment: @mac that error message doesn’t include enough details. Could you pastebin everything in the output somehow?

Comment: @mac: not really, I last used Lisp on Windows a very long time ago.  That smells as if it is not finding the file at all.

Comment: @tfb Here is the entire output: https://pastebin.com/h3Gcd99Q

Comment: @mac: that's either an SBCL bug or a nasty edge-case in the spec, and issue with Windows, or all three.  It's botching a format directive (`~` followed by a newline) because it's seeing it as `~` followed by (probably return and then newline), which is because of line endings, but I don't know what is meant to happen here.  This is just not something I can answer without a Windows machine which I don't have, sorry

Comment: @tfb OK, I gave it a shot. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @mac: you might be able to help things if you tell git to check out the files with just linefeed line endings, which I think is possible.

Comment: That did the trick. For posterity I did:

 git config --global core.eol lf
 git config --global core.autocrlf input

and the build.

Comment: @tbf Thanks for your help. Let's hope the poster sees this. If nothing else I learned something about building SBCL executables on Windows.

Comment: @mac: I'm going to report the problem you found to SBCL as it's clearly, if not a bug, effectively a bug.

Answer (score 2):

The jwacs binary can be built on 64 Windows as follows.

Install SBCL for Windows - installer can be downloaded [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sbcl/files/sbcl/2.0.0/sbcl-2.0.0-x86-64-windows-binary.msi).

Install curl for Windows - instructions [here](https://curl.se/windows/).

Install Quicklisp - instructions [here](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).

Install cl-ppcre using Quicklisp - instructions [here](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/).

Install git for Windows - instructions [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

Run following commands:

```
git config --global core.eol lf
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Clone the jwacs repo with the following command:

```
git clone https://github.com/chumsley/jwacs
```

Cd into the jwacs folder and create a file called build-jwacs.lisp with the following contents:

```
(in-package :cl-user)

#-ASDF
(error "Doomed")

(load "jwacs.asd")
(asdf:make "jwacs")
```

Finally build executable with the following command:

```
sbcl --load build-jwacs.lisp
```